# JSF how to do a GET from bean method?

Tags: jsf, liferay

I want to use a `h:commandLink` to post to my backing bean method. After that I want to open another page within the site from the bean method. How to do that?

Comment: If you want to sent a redirect ([PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)), then append `?faces-redirect=true` to the navigation case outcome of the action method associated with the `<h:commandLink>` of your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a bean actionListener with h:commandLink and redirect from action as following:

**XHTML:**

```
<h:commandLink  value="Redirect Link" 
    actionListener="#{yourBean.redirectLinkAction}">
    <f:param name="param1" value="param1Value" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**Bean:**

```
public void showAddressBook(ActionEvent ae) {
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = 
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
        String param1 = (String) params.get("param1");

        /* Do necessary action with parameter(s) here */

        String redirectURL = "Your URL";            
        externalContext.redirect(redirectURL);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log error here
    }
}
```

Comment: My URL should be of form /users/view (a friendly url), but it says: javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/users/view.jsp" not found. I am using xhtml not jsp. How can I redirect to a friendly url?

Comment: That might be issue with your mapping. Try /users/yourview.xhtml

Comment: In what sort of application, do you want to achieve that?

Comment: In Liferay 6.1 + JSF 2 + Primefaces 5

Comment: Ok, if you are using liferay, then you should have linked tag with it for better understanding.

Comment: You can pass your page URL in externalContext.redirect(redirectURL);

Comment: The `java.io.IOException` is completely unnecessary to be caught in this case. Better let it to be thrown by the action listener method - `throws IOException` or even better, just change the method signature to have a return type of String and get it to return an appropriate navigation case outcome appending `?faces-redirect=true` to it with `action="#{yourBean.redirectLinkAction}"`.